# Odoo 09: openerp.sql_db: bad query:

Tags: sql, postgresql, odoo

I was asking to debug someone code but I'm stuck with these https://pastebin.com/VnKUPCJX, it happens when this code is executed :

```
self._cr.execute("""UPDATE hr_payslip_run SET mail_is_sent = %s where id = %s""", (False, self.id))
```

It gives "bad query", don't know where is the problem with this one, I have tried to replace False with 'false', '0' but got the same erros. 
Everything goes fine when I commented it.
Here is a part of the code :

```
elif (any(st.state == 'instance' for st in self.class_ids) and not (
    any(st.state == 'draft' or st.state == 'pending' for st in self.class_ids))):
    self.state = 'instance'
    self.mail_is_sent = False
    self._cr.execute("""
    UPDATE hr_payslip_run SET mail_is_sent = %s where id = %s""", (False, self.id))

    # update the state of payslip linked to the payslip_run
    for payslip_id in self.slip_ids:
        if payslip_id.state not in ['instance', 'validate', 'waiting', 'done', 'cancel']:
            payslip_id.state = 'instance'
            self._cr.execute("""
            UPDATE hr_payslip SET state = %s where payslip_run_id = %s and id = %s""",
                         ('instance', self.id, payslip_id.id))
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Try `'t'` or `'f'` instead of `False`

Comment: I dig the problem, the real problem is a concurent acces in a record that make postgresql  give this error : could not serialize access due to concurrent update